# Symfony Doctrine Migration error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

When install `doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle` have error

```
FatalErrorException in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 4719:
Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{'

    "require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.1.6",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
    "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^1.0"
},
```

when deleted doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle in composer and all work

```
 - Removing doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle (v1.2.0)
 - Removing doctrine/migrations (1.4.1)
 - Removing ocramius/proxy-manager (2.0.4)
 - Removing zendframework/zend-code (3.1.0)
 - Removing zendframework/zend-eventmanager (3.0.1)
 - Removing ocramius/package-versions (1.1.1)
```

my version php (5.6.28-1)
without migration bundle everything fine
how to fix this ?

Comment: How about doing `composer require doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle "^1.0"` ?

Comment: no, I try many version bundle, but fix this problem when change php version to 7.0

Answer (score 0):

no, I try many version bundle, but fix this problem when change php version to 7.0

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a special symbol somewhere.
Try to remove the last line (don't forget to remove a comma on a previous line) and call the command `composer require doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle`.

It will add the right line in composer.json automatically.